# Remove json object from array of jsons in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following json in my column in posgres database.

Column items in table products

```
{
    "name": "Super name",
    "type": "Green",
    "information": [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "value": "high"
        },
        {
            "name": "second",
            "value": "medium"
        }
    ],
}
```

I want to delete json object using jsonb

```
{
    "name": "second",
    "value": "medium"
}
```

I try this:

```
update products set items = jsonb_set(items, '{information}', (items->'information') - '{"name": "second", "value": "medium"}');
```

I tried different approaches but nothing work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "minus" operator doesn't work on objects, only keys. And it doesn't work on arrays of objects either.

I would write a function that removes a single object from an array.

```
create function remove_element(p_input jsonb, p_to_remove jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select coalesce(jsonb_agg(t.item order by t.idx), '[]')
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) with ordinality as t(item, idx)
  where t.item <> p_to_remove;
$$
language sql 
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
update products
  set items = jsonb_set(items, '{information}', remove_element(items -> 'information', '{"name": "second", "value": "medium"}')) 
where ...
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=043cb2b87074cadc08e2dc639cf0188a)

Comment: @TheNightmare: works with your sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c459b650727791ec8dc5b3dd7e1356a

Comment: Yes, when i have two objects in information array, but when i have in array only one item to delete: '{"name": "second", "value": "medium"}' then function set my items to null. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bfc3723e90c93d4022d869e3754c1638

Comment: @TheNightmare: what do you want then? An empty array? Remove the key `information` completely?

Comment: Empty array will be ok

Comment: Thx. Now looking fine.