# pgAdmin4 return type mismatch when importing valid SQL function?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have the same problem this person has and the answer involves using a custom SQL function [Remove json object from array of jsons in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079982/remove-json-object-from-array-of-jsons-in-postgres)

When I click `Functions > Create` and paste the SQL code, I get error as it says the return type is not jsonb but it is?

```
ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return jsonb
DETAIL: Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
CONTEXT: SQL function "remove_element"
```

This is the SQL:

```
create function remove_element(p_input jsonb, p_to_remove jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select coalesce(jsonb_agg(t.item order by t.idx), '[]')
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) with ordinality as t(item, idx)
  where t.item <> p_to_remove;
$$
language sql 
immutable;
```

It says `returns jsonb` in function so I don't see how it is a `return type mismatch`?

I'm trying to write a query that can delete a specfic object from a jsonb array of objects e.g.
I have the name cyberpunk-2077 and want to remove it from the list:

```
[
    {
        "game": "cyberpunk-2077",
    },
    {
        "game": "new-pokemon-snap",
    }
]
```

Comment: Same result, return mismatch.

Comment: Then you must be running some different code, as the function from my answer works as you can see in the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=043cb2b87074cadc08e2dc639cf0188a)

Comment: Not with pgAdmin4 it doesn't, otherwise I woulnd't make the post.

Comment: The code [works just fine in pgAdmin](https://i.imgur.com/TtIG0Uf.png)

Comment: I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/OHrR758.png) error

Comment: you need to run that in the SQL tool.

Comment: Seems to work now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows the entire CREATE FUNCTION statement embedded in the Code tab of the GUI window.  Only the body of the function (the part between the `$$` markers) belong there.  The rest of that stuff belongs in other tabs of the GUI window.  I don't know what you have in the rest of those tabs, but clearly when pgadmin4 assembles them altogether it turns out wrong.

If you don't want to use the GUI function creator, then don't use it.  Just put the entire CREATE FUNCTION statement into the SQL window and run it.  Or better yet, don't use a GUI tool in the first place if you don't want the GUI features.